# Finding domain of $\sqrt {\arccos x-\arcsin x} $

Tags: calculus

Finding domain of $\sqrt{\arccos x-\arcsin x} $.

Now i have to find x such that $\arccos x \geq \arcsin x$. I plotted their graphs on same page and i found $x$ to be $[-1,0]$. But textbook states it wrong. May i know how?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: When you plotted their graphs, which range did you consider ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici From pi/2 to pi

Comment: According to your graphs, the inequality holds in $[-1,x_0]$ where $x_0\in (0,1)$. Note that at $x_0$, $\arccos$ and  $\arcsin$ have the same value.

Comment: @RobertZ How so?

Comment: @J. Deff What is precisely your doubt?

Comment: The graph of arccos is above graph of arcsin in [-1,0] from graph above.In $(0,x_0)$ how can we decide which graph is above and which is down?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that by complementary angles, for all $x\in [-1,1]$,
$$\arccos(x)+\arcsin(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Hence your inequality becomes
$$\arccos x \geq \arcsin x \Leftrightarrow
\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin(x) \geq \arcsin x \Leftrightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}\geq \arcsin(x).$$

Comment: Tell me with help of graphs. Thanks

Comment: @J. Deff The derivative $\arccos(x)+\arcsin(x)$ is identically zero therefore the function is constant.